# Нет вывода echo с типом строка ='<Delai dobro';

Tags: php

Приветствую, моя конечная цель сравнить строки!

Имеется переменная с типом

`string $param = '<Delai dobro';`

ВНИМАНИЕ СТОИТ знак МЕНЬШЕ.

Так вот, такую строку я получаю с файла, чтобы в дальнейшем сравнить строки(вхождение строк). И тут то проблема: строки не сравниваются, а почему?

Когда я начал выводить при echo я обнаружил что нет вывода, а при `var_dump` выводится `<Delai dobro`

А сравниваю я файлы, и ищу вхождение примерно так

```
stripos($string_from_file1,$string_from_file2,24);
```

Спасибо

Comment: Для вывода информации пользователю используйте функцию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: с чем ее надо сравнить? что означает «не сравниваются»? покажите код, который не работает, и поясните, что должно получиться, и что получается вместо этого... а то както понятно не очень...

Comment: а вывод с echo - он есть, только браузер воспринимает его как непонятный тег и игнорит... ctrl-U подтвердит )

Comment: при выводе нужно по идее закренировать символы типа <

Answer (score -1):

функция `htmlcpecialchars` более чем справляется, т.е. нет необходимости побайтового считывания.